# Variables for multiple parameters in R functions

Tags: r, function, variables, parameters

I'd like to use a variable (xdata) to define, which data to display with the vioplot function. Tried the below ways but unfortunately, they do not work. How can I achieve this?

```
library(vioplot)
x1 = mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==4]
x2 = mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==6]
x3 = mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==8]
xdata = paste("x1","x2","x3",sep=",") # Try 1
xdata = c("x1","x2","x3")             # Try 2
vioplot(xdata, names=c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl"),col="grey")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to define a variable xdata? It's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to pass the data as a variable, the `do.call` function will do the trick in a manner like this:

```
library("vioplot")
x1 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==4]
x2 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==6]
x3 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==8]

xdata <- list(x1, x2, x3, names=c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl"), col="grey")
do.call(vioplot, xdata)
```

Or is it important that the variables to be plotted are passed as a `character`?

**EDIT:** To do it more dynamically, you can du something like this:

```
cyls <- c(4, 6, 8)
cyldata <- lapply(cyls, function(cyl) mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == cyl])
xdata <- c(cyldata, list(names=paste(cyls, "cyl"), col="grey"))
do.call(vioplot, xdata)
```

The key thing is that you `cyldata` equivalent is a `list`.

Comment: Say, the field names are in a vector called colnames. It seems that you cannot simply specify the names, you'll have to somehow read up all their values and include them in the xdata list, right? But how can you do that?

Comment: If s data frame contains the data, then this will do:
    cnt = 1
    z = list()
    for (i in colnames){
      if(is.numeric(s[[i]])){
        c=sum(!is.na(s[i]))
        if(c>0){
          z[cnt] = s[i]
          cnt = cnt + 1
        }
      }
    }
    z = append(z, list(names=cn, col="grey",horizontal=TRUE))
    do.call(vioplot, z)

Comment: @lmocsi You can do something like you suggest. But I think you can do it a bit more more elegantly. I've edited my answer to give you some inspiration. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than that! No need to paste/bind/concatenate x1, x2 and x3 together.

```
vioplot(x1,x2,x3, names=c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl"),col="grey")
```

Comment: That was the starting point.
But if you want to use it on an arbitrary data source, then you don't know the variables to be displayed beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question trying to figure out how to save a configuration of parameters that you would have passed into a function, and pass them on demand in a different line. The question and top answer weren't initially clear to me, so I have a simple demonstration for those just starting to learn R.

Let's say for example that you have the function [`substr`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substr.html) that takes parameters `x`, `start`, and `stop`.

Instead of calling `substr("Hello World", 2, 5)` to get `"ello"`, we can save the parameters into a list and call the function with the parameters using `do.call`:

```
params <- list("Hello World", 2, 5)
do.call(substr, params)
>> "ello"
```

If you only want to save `start` and `stop`, you can prepend the first argument with the combine function `c`:

```
params <- list(2, 5)
do.call(substr, c("Hello World", params))
>> "ello"
```

You can also add named arguments to the list the same way you specify parameters in a function call:

```
params <- list(stop=5, x="Hello World", start=2)
do.call(substr, params)
>> "ello"
```

And the list can mix named and non-named parameters:

```
params <- list("Hello World", start=2, stop=5)
do.call(substr, params)
>> "ello"
```

If you need more complex logic, you can also wrap your call in a factory function:

```
make_substr <- function(start, stop){
  return(
    function(string) {
      substr(string, start, stop)
    }
  )
}
substr_2_5 <- make_substr(2, 5)

substr_2_5("Hello World")
>> "ello"
substr_2_5("Goodbye")
>> "oodb"
```